# Can't install Ubuntu 15.10 on HP ProBook 440

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, usb, hp

I've seen many question like this in the forum, but no one reporting this specific behavior.

- I downloaded the iso file ubuntu-15.1-desktop-amd64.iso I checked the file's md5sum and was OK (ece816e12f97018fa3d4974b5fd27337)
- I did the usb pendrive work with unetbootin-windows-613.exe and the key    has been created correctly (I checked it with the utility "Check disk for defects" in the UNetbootin menu prompt).
- Next I rebooted the computer with the pendrive in the USB slot and
  the BIOS first accessed the USB port launching the installation.
- I saw the menu prompt Unetbootin and I selected Install Ubuntu
- A first splash, as usual, with ubuntu with moving dots, appeared with dots blinking for a while
- next I saw the first two boot operation listed:

  [ OK ] Started Light Display Manager.

  [ OK ] Started ACPI event daemon.

and no more activity, the system has frozen here.
Same behavior trying "Try Ubuntu without install it"

My new PC HP ProBook 440 mounts a I7-6500U processor, 8 GB RAM and 218 GB SSD.
I add also the graphic card as kindly requested: Intel HD Graphics 520

Thanks in advance for everyone that would share some hints.

Comment: It might be a problem with your graphic card, that you did not mention, but also it might be worth a try using `rufus` instead of `unetbootin`.

Comment: thanks @dadxix86! the graphic card is an Intel HD Graphics 520, but things stopped at a very early stage, how you can see gorm the very tiny output. I will try with rufus, thanks

Comment: Let me know if with rufus it works :)

Comment: It worked fine! Thanks. Now I'm writing form my Ubuntu 15.10 ;-) see you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be worth to try using `rufus` instead of `unetbootin`.

Comment: I cannot vote your answer @dadexix86, sorry, i would do it with pleasure

Comment: Well, even of you cannot vote it, you should accept it :)

Comment: Sorry, if I've not already done it's only beacause I don't know how to do it. I try to look for how to accept, I apologize. See you soon

Comment: It was so easy... and I'm feeling so stupid right now... Ciao @dadexix86!